# c++: confusion about forwarding reference

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics, forwarding-reference

I read [this](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) (incredibly well written) article about **Forwarding  Reference** in C++11 by Scott Meyers.

Now, focus on this part of the article:

> ```
> template <class... Args>
> void emplace_back(Args&&... args); // deduced parameter types ⇒ type deduction;
> ...                                // && ≡ universal references
> ```

So, in contrast with other cases, the ellipses doesn't make the `&&` an rvalue reference, but it's still universal references.

From what I've understood, when we have universal references, we can call the function passing both rvalue and lvalues (wow, so cool!)

Now, I've implemented this function:

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
ReturnType callFunction(MemFunc<ReturnType, Args...> memFunc, Args&& ... args) { ...
```

So (using the same logic of the previous example), `&&` means forwarding references.

**But** if I try to make this call:

```
typedef vector<double> vecD;
vecD vec;
mem.callFunction<vecD, vecD>(sortFunc, vec);
```

The compiler is going to complain with `You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference`

Why this happens?

**THE WHOLE CODE:**

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
struct MultiMemoizator {
    template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
    ReturnType callFunction(std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> memFunc, Args&&... args) {

    }
};

typedef vector<double> vecD;

vecD sort_vec (vecD const& vec) {
    return vec;
}

int main()
{
    vecD vec;
    std::function<vecD(vecD)> sortFunc(sort_vec);
    MultiMemoizator mem;
    mem.callFunction<vecD, vecD>(sortFunc, vec);
}
```

Comment: *Universal* references was terrible term from the very beginning, and now it is finally replaced with much more suitable *forwarding* refererence.

Comment: Are you sure `Args` is actually *deduced* in your call?

Comment: I'd like to see real MCVE. From the snippet it should work fine.

Comment: @KerrekSB I can I understand if `Args` is actually deduced in my call?

Comment: Updated with **THE WHOLE CODE**

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code provided isn't complete (what's `sort_vec`?), and certainly isn't minimal.

Comment: Narrow it down. Try removing the function bodies. Are you sure it's the call that's failing, or the body?

Comment: include all required headers so that it can be pasted into online compilers

Comment: I think that with the last update should work, sorry

Comment: God. Some of you tell him to include more code. Some of you tell him to trim down the code

Comment: Even the Force could not tell me what to do in the case where 1. someone says that the snippet is not sufficient 2. make the code minimale 3. remove function bodies 4. give working code for online compilers.

Comment: @bolov It's almost as if they just want to see the code that's relevant!

Comment: @justHelloWorld Everyone is right: 1. There were some parts missing in your snippet, 2. Your code contains lots of stuff irrelevant to your question, 3. These are completely irrelevant for your questions, 4. A code can be minimal and working for compiler. [This](http://ideone.com/zXuA0K) could be a good MCVE for your question, and its 25 lines long.

Comment: Well, updated again with the suggested code by Master Yoda @Holt

Comment: If someone is interested, I opened this quesiton about the topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843699/make-a-code-forwarding-referencable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So first off, please use the "forwarding reference" instead of "universal reference". It better represents what it is and what its intended use is.

The first thing to be aware of is that not every `&&` is a forwarding reference. It can also be an rvalue reference.

In simple terms `T&&` is a forwarding reference if and only if:

- `T` is a *simple* (simple as shown next) type (so for instance `vector<int>&&` or `vector<T>&&` is **not** a forwarding reference).
- and `T` is deduced.

In your example `Args` is not deduced. That is because you explicitly specify the function template argument `Args` when you call it:

```
mem.callFunction<vecD, vecD>(sortFunc, vec);
                       ^~~~
```

---

Let's work with something simpler to better understand:

Lets set up the scene:

```
struct X {};

template <class T>
auto foo(T&& p) {}
```

In the next 2 calls, we have forwarding references:

```
X x;
foo(x);

foo(X{});
```

In the first, `T` will be deduced as `X&` and by collapsing rules: `X& &&` becomes `X&`, therefore we have an lvalue reference. As you would expect.

In the second, `T` will be deduced as `X` and by collapsing rules `X &&` becomes `X&&`, therefore we have an rvalue reference.

But when you call it like this:

```
foo<X>(x);
```

`T` is no longer deduced. You basically say let `T` be `X`. So if `T` is `X` then `T &&` is `X&&`, and you have the error: `p` whose type is now `X&&` cannot bind to an lvalue.

---

Holt also added:

> Also note that because of the declaration of sortFunc, this would not
>   work even if you did not specify the function template arguments
>   explicitely.

I tend to agree with him, but I would need to investigate further to be sure of this.

Comment: Also note that because of the declaration of `sortFunc`, this would not work even if you did not specify the function template arguments explicitely.

Comment: I think that I understood your answer, but my next question is: there is a way to make my code "forwarding referencable" (and so make `Args` type deduced)?

Comment: @justHelloWorld at first glance I would say no (at least not without some nasty ugly hacks). You need to specify `Args` for `sortFunc`. Maybe if you make `memFunc` the last parameter (don't know if it's possible) so that `Args` deduction happens first, but then it would change the signature of `memFunc`. But you could add `remove_reference_t` to the signature of `memFuc`'s parameters. As I've said, ugly ugly hacks.

Comment: @justHelloWorld Maybe if you post that as a separate question (but please keep it minimal) someone will come up with a good solution.

Comment: Opened this question on the topic: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842291/c-confusion-about-forwarding-reference/36842684?noredirect=1#comment61256144_36842684

Comment: To add a bit from my last comment: The standard says that *If P is a forwarding reference and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction.*, and thus you get a conflict because the type deduced for `Args...` is actually `Args&...`, but `sortFunc` template argument is `Args...` not `Args&...`.